# How to set up template and update node if all fields are in one time series of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

We now have multiple sensors for each device, and their data are uploaded together, such as temperature, humidity, pressure, etc. These data are uploaded every minute, and they are all in one piece of data. I wonder if we use Apache IoTDB to write data, we only need to build a template in IoTDB right? Also, is it appropriate to mount this template under the database node of IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, creating one template in Apache IoTDB is enough. The data sharing the same timestamp under each device, such as temperature, humidity, and pressure, can be set to aligned time series in IoTDB. Also, the template is recommended to mount under the database node of IoTDB.